# Is there a sum function that can be represented by a number of symbols as a pyramid

Tags: c#, string, int

I wanted to ask how can I represent an amount in int by the symbol "*"  in string to look like a pyramid in the command line

E.g.

```
int a = int.parse(Console.ReadLine())
a = 1 then Console.WriteLine("*")
a = 2 then write"**"
```

and so continued 3=*** 4=****

Thank you

Comment: The simplest way is probably just loop the given number of times and concat * to an empty string

Comment: @haldo Simple for a beginner in programming. I'm not saying your solution isn't cleaner but it's definitely not something you see in every programming language.

Comment: I wanted to ask how can I represent an amount in int by the symbol "*" in string to look like a pyramid in the command line

Answer (score 0):

The way i found best is to use the function "for" twice, using the function "new string".
This will create a pyramid shape in Console.

E.g

```
int a = int.parse(Console.ReadLine())
For(int b=0;b<a;b++)
{
Console.Write new string('*',b)
Console.WriteLine("*")
}
For(int c=a;b>0;b--)
{
Console.Write new string('*',c)
Console.WriteLine("*")
}
```